# The requested URL /login was not found on this server

Tags: multisite

I was making some changes in my wordpress page when suddenly it logged out and a message appeared : Pleas login...

I tried to login BUT when i click login it shows me :
Not Found
The requested URL /project name /wp-login/ was not found on this server.
I am working locally with it but I can not figure out what the problem may be.

If I redirect to :localhost/project name the page shows up but i still can not log in.

Any idea pleas?

I checked the .htaccess file and everything was ok

Comment: Is that a space in your URL? This part: `/project name /wp-login/`. If so, you can't have unencoded spaces in URLS.

Comment: Dude switched git branches. ⚽️ #firsttry

Answer (score 2):

wp-login was not found error clearly means that you have lost control on WordPress admin panel. Even if this situation looks terrible but in real, it's not.

### Situation A:  The URL might be wrong

In most cases, the WordPress installed in its own directory. When a user tries to change the default URL path of WordPress site from www.example.com/wp to www.example.com, he could be changed the site address instead of WordPress address.
[image: http://img.doubtsolver.com/ds/Wordpress-path.png]

To overcome this situation, follow steps..

1. Login into cPanel > phyMyAdmin
2. Select appropriate database (other than information_schema)
3. Select appropriate database (other than information_schema)
4. Under the option_name field verify siteurl and home rows. Mostly siteurl missed the correct URL path.

### Situation B: The URL might be inaccessible

If your site still showing the error message The requested URL /wp-login.php was not found on this server, then probably a fault in file permission level. The default file permission level for wp-login.php is 644. Sometimes it changed to 640 by security plugins. More information on how to change file permission.

Another reason is .htaccess file. It can deny accessing the internal WordPress infrastructure. To solve this issue, first download a copy of the .htaccess file; then try WordPress guide on .htaccess file.

### Situation C: The file wp-login.php does not exist

Accidently deletion or renaming of wp-login.php file can produce above described errors. So, be sure it’s presence in installed location using cPanel or FileZilla.

My friend, that’s all I have researched for you to overcome the error belongs to wp-login.php. So friends, please share your doubts and feedback via comments. You + I, we both can solve the doubt more efficiently.

Source:DoubtSolver

Answer (score 0):

As I also had the same issue.
Went through lot's of forums but found the solution as
Rename the current `plugins` folder located in `wp-contents` folder
Then tried to reach my domain, voila, it's successfully accessible and I can access my wp-admin too.
Thanks for the above solutions I'd tried them but unable to get out of rid.
I found an another way to solve hence replied.

Comment: IS this answer helpful ???
asked because long time no replies